# Angular showing error unexpected { on multiselect dropdown with index on data

Tags: angular

rser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 21 in [dropdownListMilestone{{index}}] in C:/xampp/htdocs/watchowl/ionic5FoodAppFull/App_code/emb/src/app/newweeklymilestonemapping/newweeklymilestonemapping.component.html@75:34 ("">

so variable name is keep changing by index but [data] = "dropdownList{{index}}" is not changing

here is my code

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown id="milestone{{index}}" maxHeight="100"
   [data]="dropdownList{{index}}"  ngModel #selectedItemsMilestone{{index}}="ngModel" [settings]="dropdownSettings"
     (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllMilestone($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: `#selectedItemsMilestone{{index}}` this is not possible in angular

Comment: error is showing on [data]

Comment: that's also not possible. You cannot have dynamic variable names

Comment: I have created variable from dropdownList1 to dropdownList10

Comment: @rahul Try to give the data value as [data] =“dropdownList”+{{index}}.

Comment: @Muthupriya error is showing

Comment: @rahul sorry..Try this way [data]=“dropdownList”+’{{index}}’. Could you please share the error?